# How to use Binary Serializing to store as a string?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

Basically I want MyObject to be serialized into a string using Binary Serialization.

Is this possible? If so, how to do this? Same for deserialization, from string to MyObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want MyObject to be serialized into
>   a string using Binary Serialization

This is kind of contradictory, but you can grab the bytes from a (Memory)Stream and convert them to text. Your string will not be very 'readable' of course. If you want it to be able to go round-trip you have to carefully choose encoding.

```
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(strm.ToArray());  // corrected
```

And later

```
byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
var strm2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(binary);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please post an example? So first way, you use ToString(), the other way around, how do I specify the encoding?

Comment: Certainly not `ToString`, and no `Encoding.GetString` either.

Comment: `GetBuffer` returns an over-sized array. You need `ToArray`, or you need to specify the `Length`. Otherwise you are storing the wrong data.

Answer (score 2):

There are two easy approaches you could take here, either should work just fine.

1. Use XmlSerializer to serialize it to XML instead of serializing to binary.
2. Serialize to binary and use the Convert.ToBase64String() and Convert.FromBase64String() methods to convert to/from binary/string formats.

Comment: Joan, the `MemoryStream` is convenient here but any other stream would do as well.

Comment: Thanks Henk, I will use MS then.

Answer (score 0):

Xmlserializer does not serialize read only properties and there are other limitations.